# Business Central: custome api getById does not work

Tags: api, dynamics-365, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

My problem is that I can't call my custom API for a specific `itemId` , however when I call the normal API it works as expected.

Currently I can successfully call the normal API for a specific item like so:

```
myBcServer:Port/bc/api/v1.0/companies(666e508d-9abb-ea11-bbac-000d3a492c82)/items(a5dc88b9-9abb-ea11-bbac-000d3a492c82)
```

But when I try to do the same with my custom API:

```
myBcServer:Port/bc/api/contoso/app1/v2.0/companies(666e508d-9abb-ea11-bbac-000d3a492c82)/items(a5dc88b9-9abb-ea11-bbac-000d3a492c82)
```

I get an error:

```
"error": {
        "code": "BadRequest_NotFound",
        "message": "Bad Request - Error in query syntax.  CorrelationId:  f7bc0b59-45ac-4293-9f94-108d6436272c."
    }
```

I can successfully call both API versions at `/items`. Where I get a list of all the items.

The custom API page that I made looks like this:

```
page 50101 ItemsCustomApi
{
    PageType = API;
    Caption = 'API: Items';
    APIPublisher = 'contoso';
    APIGroup = 'app1';
    APIVersion = 'v2.0';
    EntityName = 'item';
    EntitySetName = 'items';
    SourceTable = Item;
    DelayedInsert = true;
    Editable = false;

    layout
    {
        area(Content)
        {
            field(id; SystemId)
            {
                Caption = 'ID';
            }
            field("No"; "No.")
            {
                Caption = 'No.';
            }
            field("UnitPrice"; "Unit Price")
            {
                Caption = 'Unit Price';
            }
            field("VendorNo"; "Vendor No.")
            {
                Caption = 'Vendor No.';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect I need to add a property to the page like `CanGetById = true`. However, I don't know.

BC version run in docker: mcr.microsoft.com/businesscentral/sandbox:dk
Docker version: V19.03.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the page property `ODataKeyFields` to be able to select by id:

```
ODataKeyFields = SystemId;
```

Comment: Do you if there is a keyword like this for queries of type API, and maybe what that is?

Comment: I don't think there is. Queries are mostly used for aggregation of data and in that context a key does not make much sense. You problably need to use the filter parameter instead.

Comment: Yea, that was what I thought.